# Position absolute div falls under YouTube video in Firefox Windows

Tags: firefox, video, z-index

Have a total nightmare getting a div to sit above a YouTube video embed in Firefox (28) for Windows. Works a treat everywhere else and general guidance online seems to be to pass wmode=transparent in the URL but I'm having no joy..., the URL in question:

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/694545/1936099/bcccb8f6-7f03-11e3-92e0-8da2aeb3b9f5.png]

http://www.ihasco.co.uk/training-programme/coshh

As you can see there's a 'sticker' which should sit above the video at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

:Have you tried position: relative/absolute on both the video and badge? I seem to vaguely recall that was a fix for a bug I once had with a dropdown menu over Youtude videos.